# Capturing the failed sql statement from a list of sql's in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sap-ase

I would like to know if it is possible to capture the sql statements that are failing when executed from a korn shell script.

eg: I have the following statement,

isql -U ${APPLI} -S ${SERVER} -i ${InputFileName} > ${sqllog}

The inputfile has around 100 insert/update queries of which there are around 3 invalid queries(duplicates or invalid syntax) which causes the job to fail. Currently I am trying to identify the invalid ones manually. Is it possible to automate this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

If you know the string to look for, you can grep for the invalid queries.

ie.

`grep <error string> ${sqllog}`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code into a SP and use @@error and raiserror to handle error.
The following link can help you:
[Error Handling in Sybase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808846/error-handling-in-sybase)